# Detail on how (OS X) networked users works

Tags: macos, osx-server, server-administration

Couldn't seem to get any bites on this over at "AskDifferent" so thought I'd try here.

As I'm waiting for my new gleaming iMac to arrive, I'm considering buying OS X Server since it's only $20 now and offers Open Directory.

We have two MacBook Pros, so I'd like to have all of us able to log into any of the 3 Macs with our ID.

1) Can I simply switch from a local user to a network user without losing my home directory contents?

2) Is it just my home directory that is mirrored on the server? Or is it all the applications I've installed etc. For example, if I install an application on Laptop A will it show up on Laptop B?

3) I assume that when I have the laptop somewhere that the server is not available, that I can still get to all my home directory contents. They will then magically sync back up when I get back to my regular network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is on topic for AskDifferentand is a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76962/question-about-how-networked-users-work

Comment: Just because you _"couldn't seem to get any bites on this over at 'AskDifferent'"_ does not mean you can post an off-topic duplicate here.

Comment: I openly admitted that this was a duplicate of a posting on AskDifferent as the first line.  I would disagree about it being "off-topic" since it was accurately tagged, and well within the topics often discussed on this board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something of a similar nature in my home.. A Mac server and two iMacs and a Macbook Pro running off it. For this to work properly the iMac has to be running constantly, or in a state where it can be waked through Ethernet (configurable in System Preferences). To answer your questions:

1) You can do this, but it isn't automatic. You need to copy the content from the local user to the networked user, essentially creating a new user account in the process and copying all of your existing content to that. If you feel adventurous, you could try this ( http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5338 ), which is Apple's method of converting a local account to a networked one, but it doesn't require some work in the terminal, which is a little much for some people.

2) The optimal setup is where the server is the basis for all of your files, and they are simply downloaded to your Macbooks when you log in. And then any changes that are made are reflected on the server, and hence everywhere you log in.

3) Mountain Lion makes this pretty easy, and it will sync every time the laptop returns to the local network. The best directions can be found here: ( https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4154950?start=0&tstart=0 ).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I'll surely investigate the links you've mentioned - I had come across the first one.

Comment: Sure thing. If you need help.. Please ask.